# Как отключить или закрасить рамку ttk.Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

День добрый! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать рамку (highlight) у ttk.treeview? В прикрепленном показано, как он выглядит на данный момент, как можно убрать эту белую рамку по краям?  Добавление highlight=0, как в коде, проблему, увы, не решает.
[image: Вот как Treeview выглядит на данный момент, эту рамку надо убрать]

```
from tkinter import ttk

treeviewbg = '#3D3D3D'
treeviewfg = '#E2E2E2'
font = '"Montserrat" 9'

treviewStyle = ttk.Style()
treviewStyle.theme_use("clam")
#treviewStyle.element_create("Custom.Treeheading.border", "from", "default")

treviewStyle.layout("Custom.Treeview.Heading", [
    ("Custom.Treeheading.cell", {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
    ("Custom.Treeheading.border", {'sticky':'nswe', 'children': [
        ("Custom.Treeheading.padding", {'sticky':'nswe', 'children': [
            ("Custom.Treeheading.image", {'side':'right', 'sticky':''}),
            ("Custom.Treeheading.text", {'sticky':'we'}),
        ]})
    ]}),
])

treviewStyle.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
    background=treeviewbg, foreground=treeviewfg, relief="flat",
    font=font,fieldbackground = treeviewbg, highlightthickness='0')
treviewStyle.configure("Custom.Treeview",
    background=treeviewbg, foreground=treeviewfg, relief="flat",
    font=font,fieldbackground = treeviewbg, highlightthickness='0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено. За эти рамки отвечает атрибут стилей borderwith, но, к сожалению, на винде этот параметр игнорируется. Решил таким путем:

```
treviewStyle = ttk.Style()
treviewStyle.theme_use("clam")

treviewStyle.layout("Custom.Treeview", [
    ('Custom.Treeview', {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
    ("Custom.Treeview", {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
    ("Custom.Treeview", {'sticky':'nswe', 'children': [
        ("Custom.Treeview", {'sticky':'nswe', 'children': [
            ("Custom.Treeview", {'side':'right', 'sticky':''}),
            ("Custom.Treeview", {'sticky':'we'}),
        ]})
    ]}),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ttk.Style().configure(  '.',
        ...
        borderwidth = 0,  # на винде игнорируется этот параметр, но возможно было исправлено, проверь)
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, никаких изменений не произошло. Запускаю на винде